# Данные в input

Tags: html, html5, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите скрипт сохранения данных в input, например, если нужно запомнить текст при перезагрузки страницы, находящийся в `<input type="text" name="name">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно решить данную задачу используя **HTML5 LocalStorage**. Основываясь на статье: [Storing Data the Simple HTML5 Way](http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/) и используя фреймворк **jQuery** (так как я не силён в чистом JS) получилось вот что: http://jsfiddle.net/kzy2M/

Comment: спасибо, а как удалить данные из хранилища?

Comment: localStorage.removeItem('some_name');

Answer (score 0):

Также можно использовать cookies. Думаю, более удобный вариант.

Comment: @kal1sha, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @kal1sha, удбней для кого и чем? В обоих случаях, использование - это пара строк. Как отключить cookies - наверно, знает любой школьник. Как отключить Local Storage - знают гораздо меньше народа, да и многие могут даже не подозревать о данном способе хранения данных. Да, может быть отключен и JS? В таком случае, ничего не мешает применить оба способа. Но, т.к. все современные сайты так или иначе построены с использованием JS, то вряд ли кто-нибудь будет его отключать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот Angular вариация< при желании можно переделать в JS

```
this.setStorage = function(key, value) {
    value = angular.toJson(value);
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
};

this.getStorage = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
};
```